# iterating over json and adding new data (python)

Tags: python, json, loops

I'm trying to edit a JSON file. It currently has information about public trails, with URLs to websites. I want to create a new field in each object, with URLs edited to include HTML link markup. I can't figure it out.

This is my current attempt, and I'm getting

`IndexError: list index out of range`

```
import json

with open('data/querycopy.json','r', encoding="utf8") as jsonFile:
    data = json.load(jsonFile)

def main():
    for key in range (3000):
        x = data['features'][key]["attributes"]['website']
        urlvar = """<a href="{}"></a>""".format(x)
        urldata = {"url": urlvar}    
        data['features'][key]['attributes'] = urldata

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I've tried this:

```
def main():
    for key in range (3000):
        x = data['features'][key]["attributes"]['website']
        urlvar = """<a href="{}"></a>""".format(x)
        print(urlvar)
```

Which works as intended, providing the formatted links:

```
<a href="https://ebird.org/hotspot/L348443"></a>
<a href="https://www.alltrails.com/trail/us/maine/california-field-wildlife"></a>
<a href="https://www.nature.org/en-us/get-involved/how-to-help/places-we-protect/oxbow-> > nature-preserve/"></a>
<a href="https://www.sanbi.org/gardens/kirstenbosch/"></a>
```

but also pulls up an error on this line:

```
---> 13         x = data['features'][key]["attributes"]['website']
> IndexError: list index out of range
```

I'm not sure what that means, since it seems to be working? And then nothing I have tried has been able to update the json.

Thanks for any help. I'm not a professional, but I'm making a website in my free time to make data more accessible. I am motivated but not educated!

edit: data formatting example

[data formatting example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Kber.png)

Comment: Can you provide a sample of how the data in `data/querycopy.json` is structured?

Comment: It means your key is too big. `for key in range(3000)` means that key is going up to the number 2999 and `data['features']` doesn't have 3000 elements in it.

Comment: @MichaelM. added a link to an image

Comment: @SimonUnderwood hm, I tried again with range(1000000000000000) and it still didn't work

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your loop uses every value of `key` within the range 0-2999 (inclusive). However, `data['features']` might not have 3000 elements, meaning that one of the values of `key` will be too high. When you try to index a list with an index that is too high/does not exist, then you get a `IndexError`. This is the error you're getting.

Instead of using `range(3000)`, just loop over every element of the list `data['features']`. Like this:

```
def main():
    for key in range(len(data['features'])):
        x = data['features'][key]["attributes"]['website']
        urlvar = """<a href="{}"></a>""".format(x)
        print(urlvar)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is really helpful. It did remove the error in my test case example, but pulls up another error when I put all my code back together. ```def main():
    for feature in data['features']:
        x = feature["attributes"]['website']
        urlvar = """<a href="{}"></a>""".format(x)
        urldata = {"url": urlvar}    
        data['features'][feature]['attributes'] = urldata``` `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not dict`

Comment: @Henry Ok, you can change the code to use `range()` but only up to the number of elements `data['features']` has. This way you still get that index you need, `key`, but don't go over. I've updated my code, can you try again?

Comment: @Henry Did my updated code work for you?